# Swift3.0で毎日の歩数の平均を取得する

Tags: swift

Swift3.0で毎日の歩数を取得したいと思っています。
しかし、日ごとに取得したり、１ヶ月前のデータを取得する方法がわかりません。
HealthKitの歩数を日ごとの平均、１ヶ月前のデータを取得するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。
また配列に1日の１分ごとに取得したデータを入れ、グラフ化したいと考えています。
イメージはiPhoneアプリのヘルスケアの歩数表示のようなものです。
配列に1日の１分ごとに取得したデータを取り出す方法はどうしたらいいでしょうか。
ご回答お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

データベースに1分ごとのデータを蓄積して、
表示時にそのデータを取得すればよいと思います。
どこかにデータを蓄積しないとできないと思います。

ですが、１分ごとにデータを蓄積するとそこそこの容量を食いますので、
一定期間経過したら、１分ごとのデータを１日に集約することをお勧めします。

Comment: HealthKit内のデータを取得することができました。

Comment: HKObserverQueryを使用してＤＢに蓄積する感じですか？自分の後学の為にも、教えてほしいです。

Comment: let mySampleQueryDS = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: typeOfstepCount!, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [mySortDescriptor])
        { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

Comment: のpredicateの値を変更しながら取得しました。